# Reading a big language corpus without Memory Error in 16GB RAM computer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, bigdata, machine-translation

I found Google NMT using codecs for reading the input data file.

```
import codecs
import tensorflow as tf
with codecs.getreader("utf-8")(tf.gfile.GFile(input_file, mode="rb")) as f:
    return f.read().splitlines()
```

I have two questions.

1. Does above support in reading huge datasets of `size more than 5 GB` or so without Memory error in a personal computer of 16GB RAM since it is using `tf.gfile.GFile` ? I would really appreciate a solution that can help me reading huge language corpus

> without getting the Memory error

. 
 2. I have imported codecs in the code yet why am I getting this error `"NameError: name 'codecs' is not defined`" ?

**EDIT 1 :**

For 2. Getting

> ```
>  OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-7-e78786c1f151> in <module>()
>           6 input_file = os.path.join(source_path)
>           7 with codecs.getreader("utf-8")(tf.gfile.GFile(input_file, mode="rb")) as f:
>     ----> 8     source_text = f.read().splitlines()
> ```

OutOfRangeError is raised when an operation iterates past the valid input range. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Can u put in your import line

Comment: Updated in the question !!

Comment: What do you want to do with the file? Since this seems to be a line-based text file, you may be able to just read through it without ever having more than one line in memory. Also, why are you using `tensorflow.gfile.GFile` here when you just want to read the file? Why not `io.open` from the Python standard library?

Comment: What version of Python are u using , i just tested a simple two line code `Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.open("Sample.csv")
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Sample.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
>>>` it is working fine

Comment: Codecs import works. That should be my bad. Do you have an answer for my question 1 and the latest update in question 2 ? I'd really appreciate your help

Comment: Note that `f.read().splitlines()` will actually create *two* copies of your data, initially. The copy created by `f.read()` will still have to remain in memory while the `splitlines()` runs. As has been already commented, you should investigate iterating over the file directly rather than reading the whole lot into memory, if possible for your usecase.

Comment: I am sorry if I am ignorant on this. I am sure that this platform to learn from others. You mentioned that "I can iterate over the file directly"  instead of reading the whole. I have a language corpus to read and to be fed into Seq2Seq model. Do you have any sample code that performs the above which can give me more insight ? @SiHa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file size is very huge it is recommended to process it line by line.
Below code will do the trick:

```
with open("input_file") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        do_something_with(line)
```

Comment: This seemed to have worked but the Kernel died automatically. Is this can be bettered ?

Comment: ohh, But this code read only one line at a time. when you read next previous gets garbage collected so an issue of memory should not be there, works fine for me.